# Spring Data JPA with Hibernate mapping files

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, spring-data-jpa

I want to use Spring Data JPA with Hibernate mapping files and without JPA-Annotations.

But I'am facing this exception on server startup (tomcat):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No persistence units parsed from {classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml}
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.obtainDefaultPersistenceUnitInfo(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:547)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.determinePersistenceUnitInfo(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:311)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:260)

My dispatch-servlet.xml looks like the following:
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <!--<property name="persistenceUnitName" value="BLUPP" />-->
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    <!-- <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.cleanyourway.server.beans" />-->
    <property name="persistenceUnitPostProcessors">
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.data.jpa.support.ClasspathScanningPersistenceUnitPostProcessor">
                <constructor-arg value="org.xxxxxx.server.beans" />
                <property name="mappingFileNamePattern" value="**hbm.xml" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Is it possible to use Hibernate mapping files with the ClasspathScanningPersistenceUnitPostProcessor?

I get it running with

```
<property name="packagesToScan" value="org.xxxxxxx.server.beans" />
```

and JPA Annotations.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

## Briefly

Your problem probably comes from the `mappingFileNamePattern` you provide. Try `**/*.hbm.xml` instead of `**hbm.xml`.

Complete snippet:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <!--<property name="persistenceUnitName" value="BLUPP" />-->
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    <!-- <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.cleanyourway.server.beans" />-->
    <property name="persistenceUnitPostProcessors">
        <list>
            <bean
class="org.springframework.data.jpa.support.ClasspathScanningPersistenceUnitPostProcessor">
                <constructor-arg name="basePackage" value="org.xxxxxx.server.beans" />
                <property name="mappingFileNamePattern" value="**/*hbm.xml" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

## In details

### Ant path patterns

Spring uses Ant path style patterns. You can find a good documentation on those patterns on the [Ant Website](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns). Double asterisk wildcard means: *recurse in subdirectories*. It should be followed by a slash as it stands for a directory.

### ClasspathScanningPersistenceUnitPostProcessor

The mapping file detection part of `ClasspathScanningPersistenceUnitPostProcessor` takes the two parameters (`basePackage` (your constructors args) and `mappingFileNamePattern`) into account. With the suggested correction, Spring will search all **.hbm.xml* in subfolders *org/xxxxxx/server/beans/* of the classpath.

Rephrased, you cannot expect that your `mappingFileNamePattern` would be interpreted alone for the search.

Hereunder, the code snippet of `ClasspathScanningPersistenceUnitPostProcessor` that makes the job:

```
String path = ResourcePatternResolver.CLASSPATH_ALL_URL_PREFIX
    + basePackage.replace('.', File.separatorChar)
    + File.separator + mappingFileNamePattern;
```

### Small limitation of `ClasspathScanningPersistenceUnitPostProcessor`

You cannot scan for HBM files located at the root of JAR files in your classpath. `basePackage` doesn't support being empty and doesn't work with just a `"."` value.

Moreover, the underlying `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver` doesn't work with Ant style path pattern with wilcard (`*` in you case) without a root directory ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047672/pathmatchingresourcepatternresolver-spring-usage) and [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html) (first warning in *Other notes*)).

### Bug of `ClasspathScanningPersistenceUnitPostProcessor`

This class has never worked with Hibernate.

In the pre-1.4.x releases, there was [this bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/pull/24).

With [this pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/pull/24), it seems there is a new bug that prevents me from getting the whole thing working with HBM in JARs. I got a `NullPointerException` at the line 146 because `resource.getURI().getPath();` doesn't seem to work with an URI with two *:* in the protocol (*jar:file:/* in this case) and returns a `null` path.

(I will update my answer with a link to a bug report either when I have find one or posted one.)

Comment: That's a great description, thank you!  I'm disappointed with ClasspathScanningPersistenceUnitPostProcessor too